# Why is supremum of this random variable sequence finite?

Tags: random-variables, random

[image]

I don't see why this is true. For example, imagine the random variable sequence

$$(X_1 = \infty, X_1 = c, X_2 = c, \dotsc)$$

So, we have one infinity, then a whole bunch of constants. Clearly there exists another constant $k$ such that $\sum P(X_n > k)$ is finite, indeed if $k > c$, this sum equals $1 + 0 +0 + 0 + \dotsb$. So the assumption is satisfied, yet clearly supremum of this sequence is with probability $1$ equal to infinity.

Comment: The implicit assumption is that each $X_n$ is almost surely finite. Otherwise the claim is false, as your counterexample demonstrates.

Comment: Could you explain your example a little more? What kind of random variable is $X_1$? What's the domain? Is the measure of the domain =1?